# How do manage the screen layout for different devices using MediaQuery?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have used MediaQuery for Responsive Design but I am not getting the desired out. Please guide me and help me out. I am getting different UI on different mobile devices. Please tell me where am I wrong or guide me to use right code for responsive design using MediaQuery. I don't want to use SingleChildScrollView as it is Login Screen. So, I want it to be responsive for all devices including Tab and Mobile Phones of different size.
Below is my code:

```
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:conqer_music/App/Controller/UserController.dart';
import 'package:mvc_pattern/mvc_pattern.dart';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutter_neumorphic/flutter_neumorphic.dart';
import 'package:conqer_music/App/Repository/UserRepository.dart' as userRepo;

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String routeName = '/loginPage';

  @override
  _LoginState createState() => _LoginState();
}

final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

class _LoginState extends State<LoginPage> {
  late UserController _con;

  // _LoginState() : super(UserController()) {
  //   _con = controller;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (userRepo.currentUser.value.apiToken != null) {
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/Pages', arguments: 2);
    }
  }

  bool _rememberMe = false;
  Widget logo() {
    final screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: screenHeight * 0.08)),
        CircleAvatar(
          child: Image.asset('lib/App/Assets/Images/Logo.png'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
          radius: 80.0,
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 10.0,
        ),
        Text(
          'LOGIN',
          style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 28.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white),
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget backgroundImage() {
    return Expanded(
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage('lib/App/Assets/Images/BackGround.png'),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover)),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget userPass() {
    final screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Expanded(
      child: Container(
        height: screenHeight * 0.2,
        width: screenWidth * 0.8,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            TextFormField(
              validator: (value) {
                if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Please Enter Username';
                }
                return null;
              },
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                filled: true,
                fillColor: Colors.white,
                hintText: 'Username',
                hintStyle: TextStyle(
                  color: Color(0xFFbaa15e),
                ),
                suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.verified_user_sharp),
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    //  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                    ),
              ),
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontSize: 12,
                  textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            TextFormField(
              validator: (String? pass) {
                if (pass!.length == 0) {
                  return 'Please Enter Password';
                }
              },
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                filled: true,
                fillColor: Colors.white,
                hintText: 'Password',
                hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFFbaa15e)),
                suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.security_rounded),
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    //  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                    ),
              ),
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 12),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget rememberMe() {
    final screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Container(
      height: screenHeight * 0.05,
      // width: screenWidth * 0.4,
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 40),
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Checkbox(
            value: _rememberMe,
            checkColor: Colors.green,
            activeColor: Colors.white,
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                _rememberMe = value!;
              });
            },
          ),
          Text(
            'Remember Me',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 14),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget loginButton() {
    final screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Container(
      // height: screenHeight * 0.1,
      width: screenWidth * 0.8,
      child: RaisedButton(
        elevation: 4.0,

        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/MainPage');
          if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
            Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/MainPage');

            _con.login();
          }
        },

        //  if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
        // Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/MainPage'),
        //  },
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
        ),

        color: Color(0xFFbaa15e),
        child: Text(
          'LOGIN',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            letterSpacing: 1.5,
            fontSize: 14.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget forgotPasswordhelp() {
    final screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
          screenWidth * 0.14, 0, screenWidth * 0.14, screenHeight * 0.09),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            'Forgot Password?',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Color(0xFFbaa15e),
            ),
          ),
          Text(
            'Help?',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Color(0xFFbaa15e),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height: screenHeight,
        width: screenWidth,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage('lib/App/Assets/Images/BackGround.png'),
                fit: BoxFit.cover)),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            logo(),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            userPass(),
            rememberMe(),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            loginButton(),
            SizedBox(
              height: 5,
            ),
            forgotPasswordhelp()
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

flutter doesn't make it easy for you to build responsive apps for mobile. one workaround is to detect the device orientation and change the height and width of your container according to your desire. one way is the use of "mediaquery" property of your Container widget.

```
width: MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.landscape ? 25 : 14
```

this will change the width of the Container to 25 if the device is in landscape mode and change the width to 14 if the device is in portrait mode. you can do the same with height property also.